# referencing BlackBerry_App_Descriptor.xml in BlackBerry development

Tags: java, blackberry-jde

I am a BlackBerry developer. I am currently developing application for BB.

Theres one requirement, where I have to refer to BlackBerry_App_Descriptor.xml and get the version no. from it.

Then, I got to display this version no. in the app itself.

Does anybody know how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

Most of the information provided in `BlackBerry_App_Descriptor.xml` appears in the java application descriptor file (`JAD`) of the corresponding application.

So you need to read information from that file. To get the version no. of your application use the class `net.rim.device.api.system.ApplicationDescriptor`.

try this sample call...

```
String appVersion = ApplicationDescriptor.currentApplicationDescriptor().getVersion();
// appVersion will conatain the application version of the application.
```

thanks.

Comment: How can i change the current version number ?